# Prove that $\mu_{p}(A_{1}(m)) \geq \mu_{p}(m!)$ for $A_{1}(m) = (2m+1) \prod_{k=1}^m (4k-1) - \prod_{k=1}^{m}(4k+1)$ and $p$ odd.

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

The question regards $p$-adic norm.

**Notation:**

If $|r|_{p}$ is the $p$-adic norm of $r$ then $\mu_{p}(r)$ is defined in the expression:

$|r|_{p} = p^{- \mu_{p}(r)}$.

**Question:**

Define:
$A_{1}(m) = (2m+1) \prod_{k=1}^m (4k-1) - \prod_{k=1}^{m}(4k+1)$

Prove that, for any prime $p \ne 2$,

$\mu_{p}(A_{1}(m)) \geq \mu_{p}(m!)$.

**Attempt:**

From Legendre's Formula we have $\frac{m-1}{p-1} \geq \mu_{p}(m!)$.

From the strong triangle inequality: $|A_{1}(m)|_{p} \leq max(|(2m+1)\prod_{k=1}^{m}(4k-1)|_{p} , |\prod_{k=1}^{m}(4k+1)|_{p}) $

So $\mu_{p}(A_{1}(m)) \geq max(\mu_{p}((2m+1)\prod_{k=1}^{m}(4k-1)) , \mu_{p}(\prod_{k=1}^{m}(4k+1)))$

Now I attempt to find a lower bound of $\mu_{p}(A_{1}(m))$ by looking for a lower bound in the number of time $p$ can divide each product.

The number of numbers less than $4m+1$ that are divisible by $p$ at least once is $\lfloor\frac{4m+1}{p} \rfloor$. Of these numbers only $\lceil \frac{1}{2} \lfloor\frac{4m+1}{p} \rfloor \rceil$ are odd.

So we can say that
$max(\mu_{p}((2m+1)\prod_{k=1}^{m}(4k-1)) , \mu_{p}(\prod_{k=1}^{m}(4k+1))) \geq\lceil \frac{1}{4} \lfloor\frac{4m+1}{p} \rfloor \rceil$.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you computed some numbers?

Comment: I have tried computing some smaller numbers but haven't been able to note anything. I have attempted show that $\mu_{p}(A_{1}(m)) \geq \frac{m-1}{p-1} \geq \mu_{p}(m!)$ (the second inequality follows from Legendre's Formula).

Comment: $\nu_p(r)$ is not the valuation, it is the absolute value, denoted $|r|_p$. Then the problem is to compare $|m!|_p$ with $|\prod_{k=1}^m (4k+1)|_p$.

Comment: @metamorphy - attempt is now in the text of the question